# CRQS : benefits of queuing commands

Tags: php, message-queue, cqrs

I can't really understand the benefit of queuing commands in a CommandBus.

Here is my very simple implementation of a CommandBus :

```
class CommandBus implements ICommandBus
{
  private $handlerLocator;

  public function __construct(ICommandHandlerLocator $handlerLocator)
  {
      $this->handlerLocator = $handlerLocator;
  }

  public function handle(ICommand $command)
  {
      $handler = $this->handlerLocator->getHandlerInChargeFor($command);

      try{
          $handler->handle($command);
      }
      catch(\Exception $e) {
          throw $e;
      }
  }

}
```

*This implementation gets actually decorated in a TransactionnalCommandBus that's persisting Commands in kind of logging database, but as it's not the point of my question, i won't show it here.*

Now let's focus on queuing CommandBus :

```
class QueuingCommandBus implements ICommandBus
{
    private $innerCommandBus;
    private $commandQueue = array();
    private $isHandling = false;

    public function __construct(CommandBus $commandBus)
    {
        $this->innerCommandBus = $commandBus;
    }

    public function handle(ICommand $command)
    {
        $this->commandQueue[] = $command;

        if($this->isHandling)
        {
            return;
        }

        while($command = array_shift($this->commandQueue))
        {
            $this->isHandling = true;
            $this->innerCommandBus->handle($command);
        }

        $this->isHandling = false;
    }
}
```

Beside the fact it's now much more difficult to throw my exceptions, **i really don't see the benefits of the message queue...**

Can someone maybe enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rare, specific case that you need to process commands serially, in a first-in/first-out manner, a queue is a simple way to accomplish this.  Outside of that, I see no real benefit to using an in-memory queue for processing commands.

In a SOA scenario, using queuing technology (MSMQ, RabbitMQ, etc.) can be hugely beneficial, as it allows for durable messaging and enhances system reliability.  Even if a receiving endpoint is down, the command can still be queued up and ready for when the system comes back online.

Your comment *it's now much more difficult to throw my exceptions* is absolutely true in these cases, as the endpoint now needs to send an ack or error to let the client know the command failed or succeeded.  However the benefits to having a more robust system generally outweigh this minor inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you do not need a bus for your commands. I would recommend you to only use a command bus if you need your commands to be asynchronous for some reason. If you don’t use a bus then the handling of your commands will be less complex.

Nothing about CQRS says that you need to use a bus for your commands or events. Noting in CQRS says that your commands and events need to be asynchronous.

If you use a bus, then you need to validate your commands before you send them. If they fail it will be, as you say, much harder to communicate that back to the client. You can do that by raising some event saying that the command failed, but it would be much easier to just return something to the client directly.

Comment: i disagree with your assumption `To start with, don’t use a bus if you do not need to` as the bus allows to keep things loosley coupled with decorator pattern (eg. QueuingCommandBus, TransactionnalCommandBus, both decorated BaseCommandBus...) | `If you use a bus, then you need to validate your commands before you send them` i let the CommandHandler validate the command for its own merit then the aggregate for the business invariants.

Comment: I expressed my opinion that you should not use a command bus like I rule. I have changed the wording but I still stand by it, that a command bus should not be the default choice.